# Silverlight doesn't work on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10, silverlight

I'm running Windows 8 and Internet Explorer 10. I installed Silverlight, but for some reason it doesn't work and Silverlight contents never show up. I tried to install it once again and I get a message saying that it's already installed.

What's the problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Are you running Internet Explorer in desktop mode or in tiled/"modern ui"/"metro" mode? Silverlight, and any other browser plugins, are disabled in Internet Explorer's tiled mode.

> Internet Explorer provides an add-on–free experience, so browser
>   plugins don't load and any dependent content isn't displayed. However,
>   Internet Explorer for the desktop does support browser plugins,
>   including ActiveX controls such as Adobe Flash and Microsoft
>   Silverlight.

-http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846773.aspx

Comment: Well the thing is that it runs well on the Desktop mode while it fails on the Metro mode.

Comment: Yes, that is how Windows 8 was designed.

Comment: So that means there's no way for IE10 to run Silverlight ?

Comment: Only the Metro mode. This is the case with Chrome in Metro mode as well; Microsoft chose not to allow plugins in any Metro app (Flash is a notable exception, though).

Comment: Aha, I wonder if this is why Netflix wrote a Windows 8 app?